# How to set dependent slider so that the 2nd anchor moves automatically?

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I'm using the following code in the JS editor in Qualtrics with constant sum and 2 sliders. I'd like to set it up so that when participants are asked to allocate $10,000 between two choices, the slider that isn't being moved by the participant will move automatically to reflect the allocation on the first slider. The code below works so that the amount for each choice automatically updates as the slider moves, but the actual slider stays put. Any thoughts or suggestions on how to make the 2nd slider move as the participant moves the first slider?

I'm very new to coding so anything that might point me in the right direction is extremely appreciated!

```
{
var that=this.questionId;
jQuery("[id='"+that+"~2~holder']").addClass("activated");
jQuery("[id='"+that+"~1~holder']").addClass("activated");

jQuery("[id='"+that+"~1~result']").bind('input propertychange',function(){

var A=parseFloat(jQuery("[id='"+that+"~1~result']").val());
console.log(A);
        if((A+parseInt(jQuery("[id='"+that+"~2~result']").val()))==10000) {
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( 'SliderValue1_1', A );
        Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.setEmbeddedData( 'SliderValue1_2',parseInt(jQuery("[id='"+that+"~2~result']").val()));
       console.log("rturn");
        return;
    }

jQuery("[id='"+that+"~2~result']").val(10000-A);

jQuery("[id='"+that+"~2~holder']").addClass("activated");
jQuery("[id='"+that+"~2~handle']").css({"left":p*t+"px"});
jQuery("[id='"+that+"~2~bar']").css({"width":p*t+"px"});
var A=parseFloat(jQuery("[id='"+that+"~1~result']").val());
jQuery("#currA").text(A);

var B=parseFloat(jQuery("[id='"+that+"~2~result']").val());
jQuery("#currB").text(B);
```